I have a form, and the autocomplete text field is not rendering filtered values
The autocomplete cost code field is not rendering the filtered cost codes. Console.log statements of fetchAndSetCostCodeOptions function are correct, even when new job is selected. Sometimes
the cost code options don't populate initially until I hit Submit. Also hitting Submit corrects the cost codes options.
Here is my code. Please advise.
'use client';
import { signal, effect } from '@preact/signals-react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { SubmitHandler, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import * as z from 'zod';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import {
  SearchBar,
  SearchBarAllParamValues,
  CurrentDateTime,
} from '@/app/lib/utils';
import {
  Button,
  OutlinedInput,
  Typography,
  Box,
  Stack,
  TextField,
  Autocomplete,
  FormControl,
} from '@mui/material';
import { fetchCostCodes, fetchJobs } from '@/app/lib/data';
import {
  JcJobTable,
  CostCodeTable,
  CheckInFormFields,
  CheckInFormSchema,
} from '@/app/lib/definitions';
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod';

// Signals for handling form state and data
const searchTermSignalJobs = signal<string>('');
const resultsSignalJobs = signal<JcJobTable[]>([]);
const searchTermSignalCostCodes = signal<string>('');
const resultsSignalCostCodes = signal<CostCodeTable[]>([]);
const selectedJobMastKey = signal<string | null>(null);

async function fetchAndSetJobOptions() {
  try {
    const jobData = await fetchJobs();
    console.log('Fetched Job Data:', jobData);
    resultsSignalJobs.value = jobData || [];
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching job options:', error);
  }
}

async function fetchAndSetCostCodeOptions(jobMastKey: string) {
  if (jobMastKey) {
    try {
      const CostCodeData = await fetchCostCodes(jobMastKey);
      console.log('Fetched Cost Codes:', CostCodeData);
      resultsSignalCostCodes.value = CostCodeData || [];
      console.log('resultsSignalCostCodes', resultsSignalCostCodes.value);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching cost code options:', error);
    }
  }
}

console.log('selectedJobMastKey.value: ', selectedJobMastKey.value);

effect(() => {
  if (selectedJobMastKey.value) {
    fetchAndSetCostCodeOptions(selectedJobMastKey.value);
  }
});

export default function FormCheckIn() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    setError,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitting },
  } = useForm<CheckInFormFields>({
    resolver: zodResolver(CheckInFormSchema),
  });

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<CheckInFormFields> = async (data) => {
    try {
      // replace with submit action to insert sql row in database.
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      setError('root', {
        message: 'Failed to submit data.',
      });
    }
  };

  // get searchParams
  const fetchSearchParams = SearchBar();
  console.log('fetchSearchParams2: ', fetchSearchParams);
  SearchBarAllParamValues;
  const fetchSearchAllParams = SearchBarAllParamValues();
  console.log('fetchSearchAllParams2: ', fetchSearchAllParams);

  // To get the specific value of url params
  const empNoParam = fetchSearchAllParams['empno']
    ? fetchSearchAllParams['empno'][0]
    : undefined;
  //console.log('empnoParam2: ', empnoParam);
  const empNameParam = fetchSearchAllParams['empname']
    ? fetchSearchAllParams['empname'][0]
    : undefined;
  const empCompCodeParam = fetchSearchAllParams['empcompcode']
    ? fetchSearchAllParams['empcompcode'][0]
    : undefined;
  const prnParam = fetchSearchAllParams['prn']
    ? fetchSearchAllParams['prn'][0]
    : undefined;
  const shift = fetchSearchAllParams['shift']
    ? fetchSearchAllParams['shift'][0]
    : undefined;

  const datetimestamp = CurrentDateTime();

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        width: '100%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        m: 1,
      }}
    >
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Stack
          direction='column'
          spacing={2}
          sx={{
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            m: 1,
            width: 300,
          }}
        >
          <TextField
            {...register('currentDate')}
            disabled
            focused
            id='timestamp-id'
            label='Current Date'
            variant='outlined'
            value={datetimestamp}
            sx={{ width: '300px' }}
          />
          <TextField
            {...register('empNo')}
            disabled
            focused
            id='emp-no-text-id'
            label='Employee Number'
            variant='outlined'
            value={empNoParam}
            sx={{ width: '300px' }}
          />
          <TextField
            {...register('empCompCode')}
            disabled
            focused
            id='emp-comp-code-text-id'
            label='Employee Company Code'
            variant='outlined'
            value={empCompCodeParam}
            sx={{ width: '300px' }}
          />
          <TextField
            {...register('empName')}
            disabled
            focused
            id='emp-name-text-id'
            label='Employee Name'
            variant='outlined'
            value={empNameParam}
            sx={{ width: '300px' }}
          />
          <TextField
            {...register('payRun')}
            disabled
            focused
            id='pay-run-text-id'
            label='Pay Run'
            variant='outlined'
            value={prnParam}
            sx={{ width: '300px' }}
          />
          <TextField
            {...register('shift')}
            disabled
            focused
            id='shift-text-id'
            label='Shift'
            variant='outlined'
            value={shift}
            sx={{ width: '300px' }}
          />
          <Autocomplete
            {...register('job')}
            id='joblookup'
            options={resultsSignalJobs.value}
            getOptionLabel={(option) =>
              typeof option === 'string' ? option : option.JOB_NAME
            }
            isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
              typeof option !== 'string' &&
              option.JOB_MAST_KEY === value.JOB_MAST_KEY
            }
            onChange={(event, newValue) => {
              if (typeof newValue !== 'string' && newValue) {
                // When a job is selected, fetch corresponding cost codes
                selectedJobMastKey.value = newValue.JOB_MAST_KEY;
                fetchAndSetCostCodeOptions(newValue.JOB_MAST_KEY);
              }
            }}
            sx={{ width: 300 }}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                label='Job'
                onChange={(event) => {
                  searchTermSignalJobs.value = event.target.value;
                }}
                onFocus={() => {
                  if (resultsSignalJobs.value.length === 0) {
                    fetchAndSetJobOptions(); // Fetch job options on focus
                  }
                }}
                slotProps={{
                  input: {
                    ...params.InputProps,
                    type: 'search',
                  },
                }}
              />
            )}
          />
          {errors.job && (
            <div className='text-red-500'>{errors.job.message}</div>
          )}
          <Autocomplete
            {...register('costCode')}
            id='costcodelookup'
            options={resultsSignalCostCodes.value}
            getOptionLabel={(option) =>
              typeof option === 'string' ? option : option.COST_CODE_NAME
            }
            isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
              typeof option !== 'string' && option.COST_CODE === value.COST_CODE
            }
            sx={{ width: 300 }}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                label='Cost Code'
                onChange={(event) => {
                  searchTermSignalCostCodes.value = event.target.value;
                }}
                onFocus={() => {
                  if (
                    selectedJobMastKey.value &&
                    resultsSignalCostCodes.value.length === 0
                  ) {
                    fetchAndSetCostCodeOptions(selectedJobMastKey.value); // Fetch cost codes on focus if job is selected
                  }
                }}
                slotProps={{
                  input: {
                    ...params.InputProps,
                    type: 'search',
                  },
                }}
              />
            )}
          />
          {errors.costCode && (
            <div className='text-red-500'>{errors.costCode.message}</div>
          )}

          <TextField
            {...register('lotNo')}
            id='lotno'
            label='Lot No.'
            sx={{ width: '300px' }}
          />
          {errors.lotNo && (
            <div className='text-red-500'>{errors.lotNo.message}</div>
          )}

          <Button
            variant='contained'
            size='large'
            type='submit'
            disabled={isSubmitting}
          >
            {isSubmitting ? 'Processing...' : 'Submit'}
          </Button>
          {errors.root && (
            <div className='text-red-500'>{errors.root.message}</div>
          )}
        </Stack>
      </form>
    </Box>
  );
}
{
}



Please create a minimal reproduction, that's over 300 lines of code with use of over a half dozen libraries and other internal components that we cannot see.
